# Changing final structure of JSON file in a dataFrame using databricks?

Tags: python, json, databricks

I am using Databricks in python to change the final structure of a JSON file as a dataFrame. 
To read it in Databricks one can use:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
```

While using Jupyter notebook you can do it easily with:

```
df = spark.read.json('people.json', schema = final_struc)
```

But how does it work in databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you should add the path name where your file is so it might work. Like

```
df = spark.read.json('FileStore/Something/people.json', schema = final_struc)
```

Hope this works.